# How remove duplicated elements on a single-linked list with O(n) time and O(1) space?

Tags: list, duplicates, singly-linked-list

How remove duplicated elements on a single-linked list with O(n) time and O(1) space?

The elements can be any characters, numbers and they are not sorted.

For example, given  8 --> 6 --> 7 --> 6 --> 5

return 8 --> 6 --> 7 --> 5

O(1) space seems to be tough?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as you cant search in a list at complexity less than O(logn)....We have to search for the duplicates before we delete isnt? and then for each element you have to do the same so it will be O(nlogn).Is there any speciality with this list then an alternate logic can be used. Specify if there any?

Comment: No other specials. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this:

1. Traverse through the linked list and build a Hash table which would store the data and its frequency. As you traverse, if you encounter a frequency value > 1, you can remove the corresponding node from the list. This will give O(n) time but O(n) space, because of the use of hash tables.
2. A way to reduce the O(n) space complexity in solution 1 is: if you know the range of your input elements, you can have a fixed size array instead of the hash table. This would make it O(n) time and O(1) space.
3. This is to comprise on the time with o(n2) by traversing the linked list repeatedly but without using any extra memory, it can be achieved.

Since the assumption is that the input array is not sorted, there is no way that this can be done without extra memory.